# Tangent plane definition

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $S \subseteq R^3$ be open, and $f: S \to R^3$ be differentiable at $a$. My textbook defines the tangent plane as being $\{x \in R^3: (x-a)\cdot\triangledown f(a) = 0\}$, where $\triangledown f(a)$ is the gradient at $a$. I understand that that $\{x \in R^3: x \cdot \triangledown f(a) = 0\}$ is the set of all vectors tangent at $a$, what I don't understand is how $(x-a)$ 'extends' this set to a plane.

Comment: What is $\nabla f$, where $f$ is a map from a subset of $\Bbb R^3$ into $\Bbb R^3$?

Comment: The expression $\{ x \in \mathbb R^3 : x \cdot \nabla f(a) \}$ doesn't make sense. In this set notation, to the right of the colon we are supposed to have some condition that $x$ should satisfy.

Comment: Tip: use $\mathbb{R}$ to denote the real numbers. The code is ```\mathbb{R}```.

Comment: @littleO fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This means that a point $(x,y,z)$ is in the tangent plane at $(a,b,c)$ if and only if

$$(x-a)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a,b,c)+(y-b)\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(a,b,c)+(z-c)\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(a,b,c)=0$$